# All paths in a graph between 2 nodes after implementing Dijkstra

Tags: c#

I am working on a huge optical networks project where the networks are represented as undirected graphs where cycles may exist. At some point i want to find all minimum hop paths between two nodes in the graph that represent an arbitrary optical connection. I successfully implemented Djikstra with weight 1 to all edges to find minimum hop paths instead of minimum weights and modified the relaxation step to save all parents of a node instead of one (added code to save when distance is equal instead of just smaller). So now in the example network below i have going from node 0 to node 4: node 1 has parent 0, node 2 has parent 0, node 3 has parents 1,2 and node 4 has parent 3. Each node combination is an object cell in a 2d array and one of many attributes of each cell is a list of its parents (that is, a search for a parent in cell 0,3 gives the parent(s) of 3 when going from 0 to 3)

```
0 ---- 1
|      |
2 ---- 3 --- 4
```

Now I'm stuck. I want to save in a way all minimum hop paths from all sources to all destinations in the graph so i can provide minimum hop paths to any possible arbitrary connection. Can you please recommend a solution to this? I'm working on it for days and I'm truly stuck.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "as undirected" and "node 1 has parent 0" There are incompatibility in this tow things.

Comment: How big is the graph? and what is the approximate ratio between number of vertices and edges?

Comment: @Serge Yes, I misunderstood. He's into routing; I erased my comment as waaaay off the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is going to be storage.

Say that you have 10000 nodes. Then for each node N(i), you want to store the next minimum hop towards all possible destinations. This means 9999 nodes for each node in the graph, that is, you need to store at 3*N^2 node values.

At that point, going from node N(i) to node N(j) will mean:

```
k = i
while k is not j:
    h = 0
    while h < length(N(k).NextHops)
        if N(k).NextHops(h).Destination is j:
           k = N(k).NextHops(h).NextNode
           break
        else:
           h = h+1
    # if h == length of NextHops, "No Route To Host"
```

You can initialize NextHops using Dijkstra (without terminating it once the shortest path has been found): start with first node and explore the whole graph storing in each node the distance to the first node, and the previous-node supplying that distance. At the end, the tuple { Dest: i; Cost: ?; Next: ? } will be initialized for all nodes. If the graph is connected, you will have N-1 entries for each node, so you can use a 2-tuple { Cost, Next } at position i of the array.

For a connected graph the route-finding algorithm becomes then

```
def findpath(i, j):
    k = i
    p = []
    c = 0
    while k is not j:
        p += i
        c += N[k].NextHops[j].Cost
        k =  N[k].NextHops[j].Next

    return { 'path': p, 'cost': c }
```